# how to install roboguice?

Tags: android, roboguice

I am trying to setup Roboguice on my system. I followed the official [installation steps](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Installation). So I downloaded the two jar files and just pasted them into `libs` folder...

Now when I try to create a module that extends `AbstractAndroidModule` .. I cannot.. This `AbstractAndroidModule` is simply not available to me. I can only extend my class from `AbstractModule` .. but not from `AbstractAndroidModule` as suggested in [installation steps](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/wiki/Installation).

Similarly I could not find `RoboApplication` class...

Am I doing it wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: If classes can't be found, chances are you don't have the jar files on your classpath correctly

Comment: but I am able to extend successfully from _AbstractModule_.. thats also in the jar files

Answer (score 4):

I also had some problems starting developing with roboguice. So I made a really simple blogpost on how to get started with roboguice from the wery beginning. Mabye it can help you, http://henrikm.com/blog/posts/dependency-injection-for-android-roboguice/

Answer (score 1):

hleinone is right.

You ended up in the deprecated documentation because the links from the home page to the installation instructions are out of date.

If you follow the links in the main page "roboguice homepage -> Get Started with RoboGuice 2! -> Installation" you end up in the "RoboGuice 1.1 (deprecated)" documentation.

Follow the installation instructions from the top of the sidebar instead.

Answer (score 0):

`AbstractAndroidModule` and `RoboApplication` no longer exist in Roboguice 2.0. The API differences between 1.x and 2.x are big, and you should pay attention which version the tutorial is for.

Comment: ok ... I will try RoboGuice 1.1.2 as soon as i reach my dev pc and will let u know.. thanks for the reply